# Vscode: How do I stop git from displaying green U(Untracked Files) markers?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I don't understand why git in Vscode would be warming me about untracked files. If I have deleted/close the repository in Vscode. I have also deleted/close the repository on GitHub. I thought that closing the repo in vscode would prevent/stop git from ever remembering that folder use to be used for source control. Yes, once I close the repo in vscode, all of the markers in vscode stops appearing for that folder. However, once I quit vscode for the day and reopen vscode. The markers such as Untracked file (green U) shows back up. I have even tried removing the folder from my workspace and adding it back in. If I do this git automatically displays the markers such as the green U. Please help this is very annoying as I don't want this folder to be use for source control. I was only using it as a test folder to see how to set up git and connect it to GitHub. Now it doesn't seem to stop.

Help enter image description here
I have provided two screenshots

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlnUV.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pEnF.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "closing the repository in vscode"? For a folder not to be considered as untracked, it as to be tracked (obviously), or being ignored though `.gitignore`, or not be part of a tree with a `.git` folder in it (e.g. none of the parent folders contains a `.git` folder)

Comment: I appreciate your quick feedback. As I am new to git and using version control. I don't understand all the terminologies and exactly what I am doing at times. However, after searching the web for a few weeks. I found out that what I was trying to do is remove the local git repo from my computer. Which is an effect should remove/stop git from tracking cloned repository folder or directory. I do apologize if anyone doesn't understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: For mac users, you will have to make the hidden files visible by using the command cmd + shift + .(period). This will display the .git folder(delete this folder).

Answer (score -2):

For Windows users: open Explorer -> View menu -> options -> view -> show hidden files -> ok -> go to the folder and delete the .git subfolder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will delete your entire history and your folder will cease to be version controlled.